# Recursive key concatenation in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am using a firestore database, and created a schema to model my data:

```js
type FirestoreCollection<T> = {
  documentType: T;
  subcollections?: {
    [key: string]: FirestoreCollection<object>;
  };
};

type FirestoreSchema<
  T extends { [key: string]: U },
  U = FirestoreCollection<object>
> = T;

export type FirestoreModel = FirestoreSchema<{
  'chat-messages': {
    documentType: ChatMessage;
  };
  chats: {
    documentType: Chat;
    subcollections: {
      'chat-participants': {
        documentType: ChatParticipant;
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

This model is working fine.

I now want to create a type that is a union of all the keys in the model, separated by a `/`, a `string` (a document id), and then recursively get this type for all subcollections in the model.

The type that I want as output is this:

```js
type DocumentPath =
  | `chat-messages/${string}`
  | `chats/${string}`
  | `chats/${string}/chat-participants/${string}`;
```

Here is my best attempt at this, but I feel like I'm a long way off:

```js
type DocumentPath<
  T extends { [key: string]: U },
  U = FirestoreCollection<object>
> = {
  [key in keyof T]:
    | `${key & string}/${string}/${DocumentPath<T[key]['subcollections']>}`
    | `${key & string}/${string}`;
}[keyof T];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
type DocumentPath<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]:
    | `${K}/${string}`
    | ('subcollections' extends keyof T[K]
        ? `${K}/${string}/${DocumentPath<T[K]['subcollections']>}`
        : never);
}[keyof T & string];
```

So the main thing you will use is `DocumentPath`. It maps through the string keys of the object and creates `${key}/string}` and recursively calls itself if there are subcollections under the current key.

Usage:

```
// type A = `chat-messages/${string}` | `chats/${string}` | `chats/${string}/chat-participants/${string}`
type A = DocumentPath<FirestoreModel>;
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8Xa4w)

Comment: This answer gets the exact type I was asking for, and so I have marked correct, however I have realised that this type does not work the way I expected.

While this type errors if I use `invalid-key`, it will still work for `chat-messages/123/invalid-sub-collection`.

I have posted a new question with a different requirement - any chance you can take a look?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090933/typescript-spread-argument-for-nested-collection-types