# Typescript spread argument for nested collection types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am using a firestore database, and created a schema to model my data:

```js
type FirestoreCollection<T> = {
  documentType: T;
  subcollections?: {
    [key: string]: FirestoreCollection<object>;
  };
};

type FirestoreSchema<
  T extends { [key: string]: U },
  U = FirestoreCollection<object>
> = T;

export type FirestoreModel = FirestoreSchema<{
  'chat-messages': {
    documentType: ChatMessage;
  };
  chats: {
    documentType: Chat;
    subcollections: {
      'chat-participants': {
        documentType: ChatParticipant;
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

This model is working fine.

I want to create a type for a function, that will take an array of arguments as input, where each argument looks like this:

`{ collection: string, id: string }`

However I want my function to know if the current argument is not a subcollection of the previous argument, and therefore throw a type error.

Essentially I want the function to work like this:

```js
// This should work because its a valid root level document
getDocument(
  { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' }
);

// this should work, because 'chat-participants' is a subcollection of 'chats'
getDocument(
  { collection: 'chats', id: '123' }
  { collection: 'chat-participants', id: '456' }
);

// This should error, because 'chats' is not a subcollection of 'chat-messages'
getDocument(
  { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' },
  { collection: 'chats', id: '456' }
);

// This should error, because 'invalid' is not a collection at the root
getDocument({ collection: 'invalid', id: '123' })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following type:

```
type GetCollectionArgs<T = FirestoreModel> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [{collection: K, id: string}] | ('subcollections' extends keyof T[K] ? 
    [{collection: K, id: string}, ...GetCollectionArgs<T[K]['subcollections']>]
  : never)
}[keyof T]
```

Usage:

```
const getDocument = (...args: GetCollectionArgs<FirestoreModel>) => {

}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoY7MN)

Comment: thanks wonderflame! this answer is incredible.

Any idea how I would then be able to make a return type of this function, such that it will return the type found at 'documentType' of the selected subcollection?

Comment: Can you create another question for that? I have something on my mind

Comment: You're an absolute legend.

Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093783/recursively-get-objects-childrens-return-type-in-typescript