# Recursively get objects childrens return type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am using a firestore database, and created a schema to model my data:

```js
type FirestoreCollection<T> = {
  documentType: T;
  subcollections?: {
    [key: string]: FirestoreCollection<object>;
  };
};

type FirestoreSchema<
  T extends { [key: string]: U },
  U = FirestoreCollection<object>
> = T;

export type FirestoreModel = FirestoreSchema<{
  'chat-messages': {
    documentType: ChatMessage;
  };
  chats: {
    documentType: Chat;
    subcollections: {
      'chat-participants': {
        documentType: ChatParticipant;
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

This model is working fine.

I then have a method to be able to reference any collection or subcollection, that correctly types my nested relationships, that looks like this:

```js
type GetCollectionArgs<T = FirestoreModel> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    | [{ collection: K; id: string }]
    | ('subcollections' extends keyof T[K]
        ? [
            { collection: K; id: string },
            ...GetCollectionArgs<T[K]['subcollections']>
          ]
        : never);
}[keyof T];

function getDocument(...args: GetCollectionArgs<FirestoreModel>) { ... }
```

However, now I want to type this functions return type, to ensure it will correctly return the `documentType` of that collection.

```js
// should return 'ChatMessage'
getDocument({ collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' });

// should return 'ChatParticipant'
getDocument(
  { collection: 'chats', id: '123' },
  { collection: 'chat-participants', id: '456' }
);
```

Additionally, I'd like to be able to write an `updateDocument()` method, that ensures the data in the first parameter is of the correct type according to the `GetCollectionArgs`:

```js
// included for brevity
type ChatMessage = { message: string }
type ChatParticipant = { name: string }

// this should work
updateDocument(
  { message: 'hello' },
  { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' }
)

// and this should too
updateDocument(
  { name: 'ryan' },
  { collection: 'chats', id: '123' },
  { collection: 'chat-participants', id: '456' }
)

// but this should error! 
updateDocument(
  { name: 'ryan' },
  { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' }
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you remove your `FirestoreSchema` and `FirestoreCollection` types unless they have some observable effect on what's happening in the question?  I think at most you'd want to constrain the input to `GetCollectionArgs` to `T extends FireStoreCollection` defined as `type FireStoreCollection = { [k: string]: { documentType: any, subCollections?: FireStoreCollection }}`.

Comment: And what's `Chat`?  Please either define it, or even better, remove it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wvk2Bw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please first [edit] the question to reflect my previous comments). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: wow yes this approach is basically it!

The reason for FirestoreSchema is because I want to ensure that the FirestoreModel type is correct (ie documentType is never forgotten).

Looking at your answer so far, the way you have changed FirestoreCollection breaks the FirestoreSchema contract, and my FirestoreModel is no longer type safe?

Comment: Is that a question?  Then the answer is no, it is still type safe. Yes, you can change `FirestoreModel` itself to something random, but you can't plug it into `DocIO` without error.  If you have an underlying use case to catch errors in `FirestoreModel` before you try to use it anywhere, that's fine, but for this question it's at best a distraction.  Anyway, if you think there's some kind of problem with my approach, please demonstrate it to me with a code example or I don't know how to address it.  How should I proceed here? Write up an answer? Or go away?

Comment: No no please write answer! I'll update question tomorrow, as I'm out right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I'd take is to make a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types corresponding to allowable inputs for `getDocument()` and their associated outputs.  That is, given your `FirestoreModel`,

```
type FirestoreModel = {
    'chat-messages': {
        documentType: { message: string };
    };
    chats: {
        documentType: { chat: true };
        subcollections: {
            'chat-participants': {
                documentType: { name: string };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

we would define the following union of input/outputs:

```
type DocIOFirestoreModel = {
    i: [{ collection: "chat-messages"; id: string; }];
    o: { message: string };
} | {
    i: [{ collection: "chats"; id: string; }];
    o: { chat: true };
} | {
    i: [{ collection: "chats"; id: string; }, 
        { collection: "chat-participants"; id: string; }];
    o: { name: string };
}
```

And then `getDocument()` could have the following [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature:

```
declare function getDocument<I extends DocIOFirestoreModel['i']>(
    ...input: I
): Extract<DocIOFirestoreModel, { i: I }>['o'];
```

where we allow the input to be one of the `i` properties of `DocIOFirestoreModel`, and then use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to select the corresponding `o` property. That'll give us the following desirable behavior:

```
const m = getDocument({ collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' });
// const m: { message: string }

const p = getDocument(
    { collection: 'chats', id: '123' },
    { collection: 'chat-participants', id: '456' }
);
// const p: { name: string }
```

and you can write `updateDocument()` by moving the return type to a parameter type:

```
declare function updateDocument<I extends DocIOFirestoreModel['i']>(
    val: Extract<DocIOFirestoreModel, { i: I }>['o'],
    ...input: I
): void;
```

which gives the following desirable behavior:

```
updateDocument(
    { message: 'hello' },
    { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' }
); // okay

updateDocument(
    { name: 'ryan' },
    { collection: 'chats', id: '123' },
    { collection: 'chat-participants', id: '456' }
); // okay

updateDocument(
    { name: 'ryan' }, // error, Argument of type '{ name: string; }' 
    // is not assignable to parameter of type '{ message: string; }'.
    { collection: 'chat-messages', id: '123' }
);
```

---

Since that all works the way you want, our goal now is to define a utility type function, let's call it `DocIO<T>`, which takes some subtype of `FireStoreCollection`, defined as

```
type FireStoreCollection = {
    [k: string]: {
        documentType: any,
        subcollections?: FireStoreCollection
    }
}
```

and returns that union of `i`/`o` types, so that instead of manually writing out `DocIOFirestoreModel` as above, we'd write

```
type DocIOFirestoreModel = DocIO<FirestoreModel>;
```

and it would be generated for us.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type DocIO<T extends FireStoreCollection> = { [K in keyof T]:
    { i: [{ collection: K, id: string }], o: T[K]['documentType'] }
    | (T[K] extends { subcollections: infer F extends FireStoreCollection } ?
        DocIO<F> extends infer IOF ? IOF extends { i: infer I extends any[], o: infer O } ?
        { i: [{ collection: K, id: string }, ...I], o: O }
        : never : never : never)
}[keyof T]
```

It's a recursively-defined *distributive object type* (a term coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) which we get by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get a union of the properties in that mapped type.

So for each property with key `K`, we generate the desired type as a union of two pieces.  The first is the non-recursive/base piece, `{i: [{collection: K, id: string}], o: T[K]['documentType']}`.  That means every property will have an input of length one where `collection` is the name of that property, and the output will be the `documentType` for that property.  The second is the recursive piece, and is written above as three nested [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  It looks like

```
T[K] extends { subcollections: infer F extends FireStoreCollection } ? // ➊ 
  DocIO<F> extends infer IOF ? // ➋
    IOF extends { i: infer I extends any[], o: infer O } ? // ➌
        { i: [{ collection: K, id: string }, ...I], o: O }
    : never 
  : never 
: never
```

The first conditional type (➊) pulls out the `subcollections` property into a new type parameter `F`.  If the current property has no `subcollections` property, it just becomes `never` and the recursion stops here.

The second conditional type (➋) performs the actual recursive step by computing `DocIO<F>`; this gets copied into a new type parameter `IOF`, for the following purpose:

The third conditional type (➌) is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which operates separately on each union member of `IOF` and then combines the result in a new union.  I want to do this so that we keep the `i`/`o` types for the subtree separate from each other.  And it also pulls out the `i` and `o` types for each such union member into new type parameters `I` and `O` respectively.

Finally there's the actual returned type, with the same `o` type of type `O`, but whose `i` type is the current path, `{collection: K, id: string}` prepended onto the old `i` path of type `I`.

---

So there it is, let's test it out:

```
type DocIOFirestoreModel = DocIO<FirestoreModel>
/* type DocIOFirestoreModel = {
    i: [{ collection: "chat-messages"; id: string; }];
    o: { message: string; };
} | {
    i: [{ collection: "chats"; id: string; }];
    o: { chat: true; };
} | {
    i: [{ collection: "chats"; id: string; }, 
        { collection: "chat-participants"; id: string; }];
    o: { name: string; };
} */
```

Looks good, that's what we wanted!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Yhktz+ZkheLpYrUAPaCBQdwgSYA1CuX0F2cYBM3lfFJyEehVXhX4CmlMVaAARgAJgAZhoIwy1MHYdj5EC1DhH4tAtBojHtYDUCgMBwIgP1HHKfc5T5BV4NSYUaDQikaGwvCpUsWCBSVRCWDVTJslyJh8n4vVaAAFgAVgANnwwxyyIkj6NAsAqhqRFkX0WjyGnWcI0guQOKoVRkKomgGAIfB+1E0RxK9BCvic-gBIQ4TtN0qBiKgNAAGsmBAe0rLnWzoLEqAzURGgEBABTtLfLyuLgwVeJsJT0KE3DsuSp58skr51Tk7VUOUmh1K02jCLCkiopiuKZwStioPshlUoQjKsqldqQwQBAMGlABBBAeADUC0FdQ4lFoU0TP1K0jHwuBoxkNBQKYDQ4B4aoQiiQ40EYzITIjBAIpWo51rUSjTKpbbDBoHMKv5HzCrYfyGpK4LWsHe1ujWlYAGUWwAYT+ycrgoUQ7kiraITsEo+pcSooAUkAcpSYIwkRwlkAAfiEGH4bJ+JLB0nTId6RtFnkZcIxkKNYHjWHJgR7jCU2ZGeQAaUBb1IogEBlqgeRMeS7leUqiSiSgUXAuo8zIWlel5DuUWIRTUpFtcCB01o0RMUzfXDY51cGRJlWvUSPRXQgB6YHtrnoxp-m6e9DkKdlKhWZgYWw057m3Y9ktRigCm469yOHc7IQY4e4MU59-GZBAO5Xwi9OZHdh7hiMBOQ4ZJXvJ4jXlLMxppTzHNBkL+ly504ohBkCAD1jnu+4HlKh4QMt2TR6XZfl+0gA)

Comment: Incredible answer. Cannot thank you enough.